# CSS - Calling another div tag from div tag

Tags: css, html, hover

I have a div.xx-wrapper:hover in CSS which when hovered on, I want to call another 2 tags in the CSS which are div.slider-nav span.right:hover and div.slider-nav span.left:hover;

Basically I want that when the user hovers over the wrapper container, the CSS will interpret this as if the user has hovered over both the right and left slider buttons

Comment: Can you give your HTML structure so we know if this is even possible?

Comment: i think some js would be ok in these cases

Comment: This  is an edit of the jquery Carousel called Orbit. I already have edited it to only show both the sliders on hover of each arrow.

Now I just want to know (if it is possible) how another css tag can call another css tag and spoof the result as if the user has hovered over the sliders.

I currently have no HTML code, other than the implementation of the carousel

http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider

Comment: @Randell Farrugia don't edit my answer if you just wanna comment it! ;)
Yes it's possible you just put this where i putted my css comment /*CSS CODE*/ and you will be ok ;)

Comment: May be you want this http://jsfiddle.net/bVpwP/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this because it's not logical, you cannot be hover div.slider-nav span.right and div.slider-nav span.left at the same time.

You should format your css in way that you will apply those two styles when you main div : div.xx-wrapper is hover

like this

```
xx-wrapper:hover slider-nav span.right, xx-wrapper:hover slider-nav span.left{/*CSS CODE */}
```

Comment: I cannot do the comma thing, since slider-nav span.right/left have no image and on hover I change the background-image

Is it possible to change the background image of another tag from the xx-wrapper:hover ?

Comment: This of course only works if `xx-wrapper` contains `span.right` and `span.left`

Comment: it does contain them.
How can I do something similair to the following :

if(xx-wrapper=='hover'){
slider-nav span.right.background image == right.png}

Comment: no it's not from the css tag but in the way i showed you you can!

Comment: Could you please explain in further detail ? (Jerome)
I tried your code but it didn't do anything when I hovered over the xx-wrapper container

Comment: Thanks Jerome, worked like a charm. As usual semi-colons and commas remain my programming mortal enemies -.-

Thanks a lot mate :)